# How to get the current directory from the full path in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

`println System.getProperty("user.dir")` command prints the complete current directory path in groovy. How do i get only the last part (the current directory) in groovy?

For eg, if path is `/usr/bin`, I want only `bin`. Similar to the `basename` in shell.

Comment: whats wrong with `System.getProperty("user.dir").split( '/' )[ -1 ]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).name
```

ie:  create a file from the path, then get the name of the File

If you want similar to the `dirname` shell function, you can do:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).parent
```